# Like Martin Gardner's "Mathematical Games" articles in Scientific American, but for physics?

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

Is there good source for puzzles in the style of Martin Gardner's books (Entertaining Mathematical Puzzles, aha! Insight, etc), except the domain is physics rather than math?

Comment: Thinking physics by Epstein